# How to use JSONValue with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, json, ios4, sdk

here is my code and It doesn't work

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bbblllaaahhh.com"]];
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];    
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];      
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

self.city = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""]] JSONValue];
```

And here is JSON text

```
    [
{
"kanji_name":"\u30ac\u30fc\u30c7\u30f3\u30d5\u30a3\u30fc\u30eb\u30ba\u3000\u3068\u306d\u308a\u516c\u5712BigBell"
}
]
```

It reports in self.city line , What should I do ??

Yeah!! I completely fix it Here is My fix code

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blahblah.com"]];
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];   
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [string JSONValue];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[jsonDict valueForKey:@"kanji_name"]];
NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[text appendFormat:@"%@",[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]];
self.city = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:text];
```

Comment: Edit your question to show a relevant excerpt (including the top level object) of the JSON string you’re parsing.

Comment: Here you are thank for helping newbie :)

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: Here is error from my code post and code comment.
-[__NSArrayM JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5854280
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5854280'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of questions will be needed to help determine the answer to this problem.

First, can you place

```
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

after the first line and

```
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

after the second line and tell us what value it reports to the console?  This will help determine if the problem is

1) That the server never returns any data or returns the wrong data and
2) If the data is correctly turned into a string.  If either of these actions fails, it may cause an error in line 3.

Next, could you report what error the third line is giving?  There are many possible problems.  It could be that the string is not, in fact, proper JSON code and the JSON parser is crashing.

Line 3 looks like it has one obvious problem.  First, you are splitting a string based on the "\" character, which seems like an unusual thing to do in this situation.  But anyway, the order of operations will look like this:

@"a\b"

will be turned into

["a", "b"]

then the JSON parser will try to parse ["a", "b"], which will certainly cause an error.

At the very least, you will want to do something like,

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];      
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray or NSDictionary *parserResults = [string JSONValue];

// This will depend on what the actual JSON string returned from the server
// With an array, maybe something like
NSString *stringWithBackslash = [NSArray objectAtIndex:0];

// With a dictionary, maybe something like
NSString *stringWithBackslash = [NSDictionary objectForKey:@"backslashString"];

self.city = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stringWithBackslash componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""]];
```

Is self.city an NSMutableArray?  The variable name makes it sound like it should be a string.  In that case, you would actually want to do something like

```
NSMutableArray components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stringWithBackslash componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""]];

// if the city is the first element of the array
self.city = [components objectAtIndex:0];
```

You will also want to check to make sure that components, for example, has more than element because that also might cause an error, if, for example, the server returned an error or there were no internet connection.

Comment: NS(@"%@",data) show a lot of 16bit digi,like Data <3c21444f 43545950 45204854 4d4c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 .... > and NS(@"%@",string) show [{"kanji_name":"\u30ac\u30fc\u30c7\u30f3\u30d5\u30a3\u30fc\u30eb\u30ba\u3000\u3068\u306d\u308a\u516c\u5712BigBell"}]

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the code is correctly retrieving the data from the server...so the problem is probably in Line 3.

Comment: It looks like your JSON is an array with a dictionary inside of it, so you can get the string itself with


NSArray *topLevel = [string JSONValue];
NSDictionary *secondLevel = [topLevel objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *string = [secondLevel objectForKey:@"kanji_name"];

Now, everything that starts with \u... is actually what is called a Unicode character. Parsing the string with componentsSeparatedByString:@"\" isn't going to help because those are actually single characters, although the computer is showing them to you using multiple characters.

Comment: What is the part of the string you are trying to separate out, the part that says "BigBell"?